retain 0s before digit with siunitx /num notation
After reviewing my thesis, I'm faced with a problem with some numeric notations. Basically, I have some numbers in the form of digitse-digits which I have represented following this post.
However, I was wondering if would be possible to retain the leading 0s as per the output of the computation which generates them. See below for a MWE.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}

\begin{document}

\dots (error rate: \num{4.11e-07} and \num{1.89e-07}).

\end{document}

Thanks in advance!

siunitx, version 3.3.12 (2024-02-15), does not seems to provide the requested feature in the question (fixed number of digits for the exponent allowing leading zeros or to disable parsing of the exponent only).
There is a workaround by defining a new token as new zero that is kept by
siunitx.

\protected\def\0{0}
\sisetup{input-digits=0123456789\0}
\dots (error rate: \num{4.11e-\07} and \num{1.89e-\07}).

Remarks:

If \0 is already used for other purposes, you have to use a different control sequence.
\protected seems to be strong enough to prevent siunitx from removing the "protected" zero from the exponent. (It is also "weak" enough to allow options of siunitx that requires parsing the exponent as number like exponent-mode=engineering. In this case, the leading zero is gone.
The main disadvantage is that the source text needs to be changed to replace
the leading 0 in the exponents by \0.

Also, contact the author of the package to make a feature request and explain the requirement for number formatting for your thesis. Maybe, he will add and implement some new options that will help in for this case.

For a feature request, visit siunitx on Github.

@Heiko Oberdiek very kind, thanks for the help! For my use and in my situation, this solution works perfectly. However, I will make sure to follow up with a GitHub issue to see if this can be fixed!
